# Is it a norm or seminorm

Tags: functional-analysis

Currently I am trying to do some functional analysis and I am not sure about some task from there. The exercises are to check if the function $N_i:\ell_1\to \mathbb{R}$ defines a norm or seminorm:

1.$N_1(x)=\max_{n\ge 2}|x_n| + |\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n|$

2.$N_2 (x)=\sup_{m\in \mathbb{N}} |\sum_{n=1}^m x_n|$

These will be for $N_i:C([a,b])\to \mathbb{R}$

3.$N_3 (f)=\int_a^b |f(x)|dx$

4.$N_4 (f)=|\int_a^b f(x)dx|$

The hard part for me is to show the triangle inequality. 
For Ex.3. Is it direct from Minkowski inequality for p=1?
Ex.4. We have $|\int_a^b f(x)dx| \le \int_a^b |f(x)|dx$ and further like  in Ex.3, but also for $f(x)=x-\frac{a+b}{2}$ we have $N_4(f)=0$, so its seminorm.

Are my thoughts correct? How I can get the triangle inequality for Ex 1 and 2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is $N_{4}(f)$ so weirdly defined? Do you mean $|\int_{a}^{b} |f(x)| dx |$? If yes, then we have $N_3 = N_4$

Comment: It's defined  $|\int_a^b f(x)dx|$. Sory for a typo.

Comment: $N_4(f+g)=|\int  (f+g)dx| = |\int fdx+\int gdx| \le |\int fdx|+|\int gdx|=N_4(f)+N_4(g)$.